# ASp.net tooth charting components?

Tags: asp.net

Just wondering if any of you have idea how to display tooth charts (dental related) in asp.net.
Any links/references would be helpful.
Thanks
N

Comment: Could you give us a little more information, what format are the charts in? Images? XML? Text files? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what type of charts you need to generate, as it's somehow business related, you can use [Microsoft Chart Control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart).
The Microsoft Chart Control is a free, full-featured chart control package which enables developers to easily add rich data visualization to ASP.NET and Windows Forms applications.

You can download sample environment which includes over 200 samples for both ASP.NET and Windows Forms and include the C# Source Code for each sample.